# Why does a cumulative distribution have the quality that $P(X<b)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[P\left(X\leqslant b-\frac1n\right)\right]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, cumulative-distribution-functions

I came across the following passage in Ross' "First Course in Probability":

> ***If we want to compute the probability that X is strictly less than b , we can apply the continuity property to obtain:
> $$P\bigl(X<b\bigr)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[P\left(X\leqslant b-\frac1n\right)\right].$$***

The continuity Ross is referring to, is the ***right*** continuity of the cumulative function but the property he mentions seems to me to be a property of a ***left*** continuity since the sequence $b-\dfrac1n$, where $n$ goes to infinity, is an **increasing** sequence that converges to $b$ from left to right.
Will be grateful for any enlightening remarks on this.

Comment: Indeed this does seem to be using left continuity, so I don't think the result is true in general. Is he talking about a particular distribution?

Comment: The result is true in general. Note that the limit is not the cumulative distribution function!

Comment: Thanks (Enforce) for your interest. In answer to your question -No. He's talking about general properties of a cumulative distribution function.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X < b)$ is not the cumulative distribution function evaluated in $b$. That would be $\mathbb{P}(X \leq b)$. Left continuity would imply that $\mathbb{P}(X < b) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq b)$ which is indeed not the case in general.

Comment: To Furrer. Thanks for your comment. I realize that p(x<b) or the limit used to find it is not a the cumulative function value of "b" (which is p(x<=b). My question is why do I use a left limit to find p(x<b) when the only assured continuity of a cumulative function is the right one.

Comment: I think you can't; not without reference to measure theory (see me answer below). I do not know Ross' book, but his argument seems sloppy at best. Even with no reference to measure theory, you may still convince yourself that the result is true for continuous cumulative distribution functions and for cumulative distribution functions arising from discrete random variables. This most likely anyway covers all cases relevant in a first course on probability theory.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you. Ross states (with insufficient proof) that you might find the probability $\mathbb{P}(X < b)$ by calculating the relevant left limit of the cumulative distribution function. To give a rigorous proof, one needs a mathematical concept of probability measures to go from $\mathbb{P}(X < b)$ to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X \leq b - 1/n)$. This is usually not part of an introductory course on probability theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The continuity Ross is referring to, is the ***right*** continuity of the cumulative function...

Not quite. Ross is referring to "probability as a continuous set function", which he states as a proposition as "If $\{E_n, n \ge 1\}$ is either an increasing or decreasing sequence of events, then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}P(E_n) = P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} E_n\right)$$

" In the ninth edition this is stated and proven in section 6 of chapter 2.

---

Left continuity of the cdf would say

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P\left(X \le b - \frac{1}{n}\right)= \lim_{n\to\infty} F\left(b - \frac{1}{n}\right) =   F\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} b - \frac{1}{n}\right)  = F(b) = P(X \le b)$$

which Ross does **not** claim.

Comment: You are looking at a different chapter in the book. Please check out section 4.10 titled: Properties of the Cumulative Distribution Function. In that section he writes your first (most left equation) but with the probability on the left being smaller without equal. I agree that this is not a claim for left continuity but he sees it as being directly implied by RIGHT continuity. And that is exactly my question. How does he infer his claim from right continuity?

Comment: Is this the version you are working with, @Elazar? http://www.seyedkalali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/A-First-Course-in-Probability-8th-ed.-Sheldon-Ross.pdf. The continuity property Ross here refers to is clearly the aformentioned continuity properties from Section 2.6: "Properties 2, 3, and 4 all follow from the continuity property of probabilities (Section 2.6)". By the way, you'll notice that the final part of my answer is closely related to Ross' arguments here and in Section 2.6.

Comment: But maybe not clearly enough: your confusion is understandable. Would be better if Ross gave a direct reference to his Proposition 2.6.1.

Comment: @Elazar Ross talks about "continuity of probabilities" in section 4.10 **before** he proves property 4(right continuity of the cdf), so he's talking about continuity of $P$ and not $F$. He uses continuity of $P$ to prove right continuity of $F$ and to prove what you're talking about.The limit is applied to the event and not the argument of the cdf. Section 2.6 is where Ross proves facts about continuity of $P$. Ross uses these results from 2.6 to prove results in 4.10.

Comment: Just read the quoted section again and you're both (Coriolanus and Furrer) absolutely right. I was mistakenly focusing on the right continuity property of the cmd and viewing it as the source of all the results in the  section (4.10), instead of seeing it as just one of many results of the general continuity property of probability (mentioned in section 2.6.) Thank you both (Coriolanus and Furrer) for clearing this up for me.

Comment: As an afterthought (and a little in my defence for misinterpreting Ross' argument..-:)  ) I note that the probability P(x<b) is actually equal to the left sided limit of the CMD at point b and this just after he has mentioned the RIGHT continuity of the CMD...

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of continuity of measures. (As pointed out in a different answer, please consult Section 2.6 in Ross'.)

**Continuity from below**

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{E})$, and let $E,E_1,E_2,\ldots$ be sets in $\mathcal{E}$. If $E_n \nearrow E$, then $\mu(E_n) \nearrow \mu(E)$.

**Application**

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a background probability space, and let $X : (\Omega,\mathcal{F}) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ be some random variable. Denote by $X(\mathbb{P})$ the pushforward measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ given by $X(\mathbb{P})(A) = P(X \in A)$ for $A\in\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $b\in\mathbb{R}$, let $B = (-\infty,b)$, and let $B_n = (-\infty,b-1/n]$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Clearly, $B, B_1, B_2, \ldots$ are subsets of $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Note that $B_n \nearrow B$. Then according to the continuity from below of the probability measure $X(\mathbb{P})$, we find that
$$
X(\mathbb{P})(B_n) \nearrow X(\mathbb{P})(B).
$$
Rewriting according to the definition of the pushforward measure yields
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X \leq b-1/n) \nearrow \mathbb{P}(X < b)
\end{align*}
as desired.

**Direct proof from axioms**

Recall Kolmogorov's axioms: $\mathbb{P}$ is non-negative, $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1$, and if $E_1,E_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of mutually exclusive events, then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\!\left(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(E_n).
\end{align*}
This last axiom is also known as subadditivity.

Let $F_n = (X \leq b-1/n)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Note that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty F_n = (X < b)$. Define $E_n$ recursively by $E_1 = F_1$, $E_2 = F_2 \setminus F_1$, $E_3 = F_3 \setminus F_2$, and so on. For example, $F_2 = (b-1 < X \leq b-1/2)$. Note that $E_1,E_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of mutually exclusive events, and that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n = \cup_{n=1}^\infty F_n = (X < b)$. Then by twice applying first countable subadditivity and then finite subadditivity (i.e. Kolmogorov's last axiom),
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X < b) &= \mathbb{P}\!\left(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(E_n) \\
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{P}(E_n) \\
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \mathbb{P}(\cup_{n=1}^N E_n) \\
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \mathbb{P}(F_N) = \lim_{N \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(X \leq b - 1/N).
\end{align*}

Comment: Your'e probably right but I am unfamiliar with the term "pushforward measure". I was hoping for a more intuitive answer which does not use measure theory terminology. I'll look into what you wrote. Thanks

Comment: I am afraid there is no general answer that avoids measure theoretic terminology.

But you might convince yourself that Ross' statement is true for continuous cumulative distribution functions (trivial) and cumulative distribution functions arising from discrete random variables. This should be sufficient to cover all cases relevant to an introductory course on probability theory.

Comment: Give me some time and I'll make an edit which proofs the statement directly from Kolmogorov's probability axioms. (I hope you are familiar with these?)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a direct proof. Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. I am familiar with the Kolmogorov axioms but still need  some time to follow this.

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask further questions if necessary. Also please accept an answer when you are ready.

Answer (score 2):

The event $X<b$ is the union of all events $X\le b-\frac 1n$ (namely, $X<b$ if and only if there exists some $n$ such that $X\le b-\frac 1n$), hence $P(X<b)$ is the supremum of all $P(X\le b-\frac 1n)$.

Comment: Ok. But given that the continuity is right continuity, shouldn't I use the infimum of 
p(X≤b+1/n) say, for finding p(x<b)?

Comment: Some property, such as continuity, of the probability measure involved is required to write "hence (...)". See my answer below.

Comment: @Elazar no, that would give you $P(X \leq b)$ (not  $P(X < b)$).

Comment: I agree. So how do you explain his inference?